# Parse.com create object with reference to user

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform

I am writing an AngularJS application with Parse.com Javascript SDK;

I would like send a request to create an object called "Activity" where the "Activity" object has a reference to the creator user (for example: column "owner").

How do I do that? do I need Cloud code for that? If not, wouldn't that be a security breach where anyone can use some client id to create objects?

Answer (score 0):

The secure (and right) way to achieve this is to implement a Create function in server side. For example: if the Activity has a "title" field, and we'd like to add a reference to another object as a Relation column (in our case: User), we would write the following Cloud code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("createActivity", function (request, response) {
    var Activity = Parse.Object.extend("Activity");
    var activity = new Activity();

    activity.set('title', request.params.activity.title);
    activity.set('user', Parse.User.current());

    activity.save(null, {
        success: function (activity) {
            response.success({activity: activity});
        },
        error: function (activity, error) {
            response.error({ activity: activity, error: error });
        }
    });
});
```

From our angularJS app, we consume the Cloud code like any other Cloud code function:

```
    function create() {
        Parse.Cloud.run('createActivity', { activity: $scope.activity }, {
            success: function (response) {
                // object created!
                }, 
            error: function() {}
        });
    };
```